# async loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to sum up the results which got from a series of async call

```
let sum = 0;
for(const id  of ids) {
  const res = await getRes(id);
  sum += res;
}
```

Is this a valid way to do it? Any better solution?

Comment: Sure, unless you can make all the calls to `getRes`  at the same time, in which case you `Promise.all` them and then sum them up.

Comment: `const sum = await Promise.all(ids.map(id =>getRes(id))).then(nums=>nums.reduce((a,b)=>a+b));`

Answer (score 2):

The code that you have written seems to be correct.

In order to validate it you can write some unit tests, I can't say how difficult it is because I don't know what `getRes` is doing and what external dependencies (if any) you have to mock. Generally speaking you should take the habit of unit testing your code: one of the benefits it brings to the table is offering you a way to validate your implementation.

You can also consider the idea of getting the results in parallel, this can actually speed things up. Again I don't know what `getRes`is doing, but I suppose it performs some sort of IO (e.g.: a database query). Given the single thread nature of Javascript, when you have a bunch of **independent** asynchronous operations you can always try to perform them in parallel and to collect their results, so that you can aggregate them later. Please notice the bold on the word **independent**: in order to perform a bunch of operations in parallel they need to be independent (if they are not, the correctness of your code will be invalidated).

Since you are performing a sum of number, it is safe to compute the addends in parallel.

This is the simplest possible parallel solution:

```
async function sum(ids) {
    const getResTasks = ids.map(id => getRes(id));
    const addends = await Promise.all(getResTasks);
    return addends.reduce((memo, item) => memo + item, 0);
}
```

Pay attention: this is a naive implementation. I don't know how many items the ids array can contain. If this number can possibly be huge (thousand of items or more) a code like the previous one could create an **heavy load** on the external dependency used to get the sum addends, so some precautions to limit the degree of parallelism should be taken.